# Can I use Google's Safe Browsing logo?

Tags: licensing, logos

I'm using Google's [Safe Browsing API](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/v4/lookup-api). I want to put their logo on the bottom of my input form so that people know I'm using the API. However, I'm not sure if it is legal.

On the bottom of the page it says:

> *Except as otherwise noted, the content of this page is licensed under the [Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 License](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/), and code samples are licensed under the [Apache 2.0 License](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0). For details, see our [Site Policies](https://developers.google.com/terms/site-policies). Java is a registered trademark of Oracle and/or its affiliates.*

I'm not sure if the logo is under Creative Commons. The logo is the [green shield](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/images/SafeBrowsing_Icon.png).

Answer (score 2):

Google isn't very clear on this issue, but their [Permissions](https://www.google.com/permissions/) page does say:

> All of our brand features are protected by applicable trademark, copyright and other intellectual property laws. If you would like to use any of our brand features on your website, in an ad, in an article or book, or reproduce them anywhere else, or in any other medium, you'll need to receive permission from Google first. And please note that the user experience with all our products should never be altered.

Even though that blurb that you included from the bottom of the [Lookup API](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/v4/lookup-api) page does seem to indicate that the logo is covered under a Creative Commons license, I would contact Google to explicitly get their permission before using any of their logos or icons. You can file a formal request with Google here:

https://services.google.com/fb/forms/permissionsbranden/